# question regarding edge space

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and it's edges space $\mathcal{E}(G)$ in the book by Diestel it defines

> given two edges sets $F,F'$ and their coefficients $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{m}$ and $\lambda_{1}',...,\lambda_{m}'$ $\langle F,F'\rangle=\lambda_{1}\lambda_{1}'+...+\lambda_{m}\lambda'_{m} \in \mathbb{F}_{2}$.

Now i'm guessing they force the sum to be modulo $2$ otherwise clearly it does not need to be right? Secondly what is the importance mathematically of defining this product in this way?

I am new to vector spaces, and have found that a similar notation is used in "inner product spaces" so i'm guessing the product defined above would be an inner product space? Which would explain why it's elements are mapped to $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.

Comment: After looking at wikipedia perhaps its a semi-inner product?

Comment: Yes, the arithmetic is all modulo $2$, and yes, it’s a semi-inner product. It behaves enough like an inner product to be similarly useful; **Theorem** $\mathbf{1.9.4}$ is an example. By the way, you can get the angle brackets with `\langle` and `\rangle`.